# Importing data from JSON using python

Tags: python, json

Hi I am new to python and I am trying to import a Dataset from JSON file in the repository using Python

```
import json
with open ('dataforms.json','r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for row in data:
        print (row[Flood])
```

this code is throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ayush\Desktop\js2.py", line 5, in <module>
    print (row[Flood])
NameError: name 'Flood' is not defined
```

Comment: `print (row['Flood'])`

Comment: You could help yourself by posting the structure of this JSON file on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `Flood` is a string? In which case you need to put quotes around it, or Python thinks it is a variable name.

```
print (row['Flood'])
```

Comment: @ayushnigam What is "not working"? Same error message? New one? I can't read your mind or see your computer screen.

Comment: print (row) prints everythin from the file, i just want 1 row

Comment: The answer is `print(row['Flood'])` not `print(row)`

Comment: @ayushnigam  (in response to wanting just 1 row) There isnt a 'row' in json.  It defines what turns into dictionary, lists and values in python.  You need to select the part of that structure that you want printed.